# Excel Formula - if values in columns all contain X then return

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula

I have an excel formula where 3 columns (A,B, C)  check values and if true, return "OK", I have a fourth column (D)  where I want to check if all 3 columns contain "OK" then return text.  I have tried various formulas and changing OK to blank and using ISBLANK formula but still not working. Can anyone please advise?

The formula in A,B C is =IF(A2 = "Cell Site Change - Implementers","OK","Missing Site Change IMP")

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A3,"OK")=3,"Yes","No")
```

Where A=A1, B=A2, C=A3

And the value for the 3 cells is with the formula:

```
=IF(A1="Cell Site Change - Implementers", "OK", "NOT OK")
```

You can extend it for multiple cells by using so you don't have to compute the number of cells you compare:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:A5,"OK") = COUNTIF(A1:A5,"*"),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. Will this work if OK values are in A2, B2, and C2 and check value is D2 - ie if A-C = Ok then "All OK"?

Comment: hi,Managed to get it working now with the following; - =IF(COUNTIF(J4:L4,"OK")=3,"OK","AMEND"). Thank you - it was driving me round the twist trying to work it out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AND function:

```
= IF(AND(A3="OK";B3="OK";C3="OK");"everything is great";"something is missing")
```

where A, B and C are in A3, B3 and C3 respectively.

Comment: thank you very much - got it sorted. much appreciated.